# get distinct value of year from DateTime using lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, lambda, distinct

I have DateTime data in my database .
For example ,

```
ID   Date         Remark
==========================
1    2013-10-22   
2    2013-10-23   
3    2013-10-24   
4    2012-10-01   
5    2012-10-02
```

What I want to do is to bind distinct value of year `(2013,2012)` in combo(dropdownlist) .

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlYear" Width="100%" 
DataValueField="Date"  Font-Size="14px" DataTextField="Date" 
DataTextFormatString="{0:yyyy}" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

This is how I bind datasource ,

```
ddlYear.DataSourse = db.DBContext.DateTables.Select(x =>   
x.Date.Value.Year).Distinct().ToList();
ddlYear.DataBind();
```

But there is an error ,

> *Object of type System.Int32 does not have a Date property.*

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Which line you got this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlYear" Width="100%" Font-Size="14px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

`DateTime.Year` is Int32 not DateTime, you don't need to format it :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Indeed I am :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `DataValueField="Date"`, `DataTextField="Date"` and `DataTextFormatString="{0:yyyy}"`